# Any samples for mvc6 with signalr?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a full-working `ASP.NET MVC` application `(.NET Core, ASP.NET MVC 6)`.

I would now like to add a `signalr` to my application. Any samples for `MVC` with `signalr`?

Answer (score 31):

[The MusicStore sample on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore) use `signalR`
and the [BugTracker sample](https://github.com/aspnet/BugTracker) also
and you have a [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/tree/dev/samples/SignalRSample.Web) in the [SignalR-Server](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) repo
Or you can look at [my sample](https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle) on GitHub

Comment: As of now the samples don't seem to work. Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server 3.0.0-beta5 needs an update to work with MVC 6.0.0-rc1-final. The app.UseSignalR() and services.AddSignalR() in Startup.cs don't exist any more.

Comment: @Ovi, did you try my sample ? It should work for `RC1`

Comment: @aguafrommars: didn't work, I'm using "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final", not "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-*". The problem will solve itself out in a couple of months anyway as things get out of RC. In the meantime I implemented a layman's version of plain JavaScript long-pooling as presented [here](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery/)

Comment: @Ovi, use the master branch, it's for rc1. The dev branch use rc2.

Comment: latest [official roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap) says that SignalR is tentatively planned after Asp.Net Core 1.0.0 RTM

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are any yet.

The next version of SignalR, version 3, is designed for ASP.NET Core, SignalR 2 doesn't support this.
If you look on the ASP website https://www.asp.net/learn it doesn't mention that you can use SignalR with ASP.NET Core .

Since ASP.NET Core makes use of NodeJS rather then NuGet for client-side libraries, a Node module would probably be created for SignalR.
Only time will tell what SingalR 3 will look like.

This is also a relevant question [What is the development status of SignalR 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604086/what-is-the-development-status-of-signalr-3)