# What is the development status of SignalR 3?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Based on my understanding, [the old SignalR repository](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) is dead: there were no commits for a year (ironically, the guys who previously committed to it, now commit to Node,js), dozens of issues without response (we experienced a bug and had to downgrade to a version that's two years old).

There's a [SignalR-Server](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) repository which is a part of ASP.NET. It was supposed to be released with ASP.NET 5 (Q1 2016) but according to roadmap, it will be released later (Q3 2016). So I guess this is the repository where the actual SignalR development is going on. But the appropriate [client repository](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-JS) is empty. So should I use the client from the old repository and a server from the new one? That's extremely confusing.

Comment: Just because a certain version is *finished* doesn't mean it's dead. You confused SignalR 2.0 which is for ASP.NET 4.5 (finished, done) with SignalR 3 which is for ASP.NET 5 (completely new)

Comment: If the question is *which version to use*, use the latest stable from NuGet. Each of the versions targets a different framework so there is no danger of mixing them up. If the question is *is SignalR dead?* the answer is no, not at all.

Comment: I don't understand why these repositories aren't named with the version for major incompatible updates like this. It gets super confusing - especially when the documentation for the repository says NOTHING about versions or roadmaps. Why not SignalR-ServerNetCore?

Answer (score 7):

There will be a version 3 of signalR included in ASP.NET 5. The development team aim for a release by mid-2016. See this [roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#future-work)

#### Update #1 (April 2018):

- SignalR 3 will be shipped with ASP.NET Core 2.1 (see [ASP.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap/#signalr))
- ASP.NET Core 2.1 will be released `mid-year 2018` (see [ASP.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/02/asp-net-core-2-1-roadmap))
- [New GitHub repo](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR)

#### Update #2 (June 2018)

- ASP.NET Core 2.1 has been released (see [ASP.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-net-core-2-1/))

Comment: No, it wont. ASP.NET will be released by Q1 while SignalR support will be added by Q3/Q4

Comment: @Idsa I don't think a quarter's difference in an OSS project is that important. Nor does the roadmap specify which feature will be ready when. After all, if you *do* want to target ASP.NET 5, you'll have to use v3. If not, it doesn't matter when it comes out

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, SignalR support for ASP.NET 5 release will happen in a year. That raises a question whether it is a good idea to use it now

Answer (score 3):

Id'say alive and kicking, https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/pulse I think you may have been looking at commits to the master branch only.

Comment: Actually, the OP was looking at the wrong versions. The old repository is v2 which supports ASP.NET 4.5 and is finished. SignalR-Server is v3 for ASP.NET 5.

Comment: The OP stated that there had been no commits to the "old repository" for a year. That may seem true if you only look at commits on the master branch, on the dev branch however commits still occur frequently.

Comment: Indeed, although in this case the OP is also confused about which version does what. A *far* better indicator of a project's state though are answered issues, not commits. And that *does* show up in Pulse

Comment: @RobbertDraaisma, you're right, I was looking to commits to master. My bad. But what makes you think SignalR repository is "alive and kicking"? No commits, no answers to issues (the closed issues were closed by users themselves). The goal of this repository is not clear (as there are both server and client repositories in asp.net 5 repositories)

Comment: @Idsa the purpuse is very clear - it's the repository of v2, which *does* have a stable version. What is actually your question? Which ASP.NET are you targetting?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I'm currently targeting 4.5 (and have to use a 2 years old version due to bugs in current version). So I'm considering migrating to ASP.NET 5 but not sure if everything is stable enough (SignalR release for ASP.NET 5 is a year away)

Comment: @Idsa what bugs? 4.5.2 *fixes* the bugs in 4.5. Are you referring to ASP.NET 4.6? 5 is different enough that you should carefully consider what needs changing - quite a lot from the project strucutre up.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of SignalR has been released as a part of .Net Core 2.1 (30.05.2018)