# SignalR general questions

Tags: signalr, signalr.client, signalr-2

I have in fact couple question regarding that library, hopefully anyone to answer avoiding create separated topics. If that's not the place to ask let me know where please. Nevertheless i think your answer find other people to get knowledge as well because saw lot of confusions on internet regarding that staff.

Q's:

> 1. I see that current SignalR version is 2.2.3 however i cannot find any relase notes for that - only for 2.2.2, does somebody knows why?
> 2. Is there any risk updating from 2.2.1 to 2.2.3? I have such big appliation in my current version would all work as it was or is there
>      anything that has to be changed migrating to most recent version?
> 3. Is there any diffrence with SignalR, SignalR2 and SignalR ASP.NET? I am bit confused
> 4. Is SignalR also permitted to be developed in commercial use or do i need any specific license?
> 5. I've found lot of samples based on signalR howeever could you provide most up to date sample showing all recent feature from current
>      release.
> 6. Last question: Is there any significant change comparing version 2.2.1 and 2.2.3 especially related to async usage or it's more like almost the same creating server/client apps?
> 7. On this page i see nice tutorial how to use signalr, however is this page official always updating to the current signalr release?https://www.asp.net/signalr . Aksing because saw also github page any others. If not could you direct me to correct one please.
> 8. Is this sample up to date regarding new features?
> 9. There was chat saple available JabR if recall, is there still a working link to this sample?
> 10. As far as i was able to create some chat i wonder how JabR stores chat conversations history in the way that every client whom joined chat could see conversation which was done when he was not connected. In other words how to make every new joiner to chat to see all conversations already in chat by other users is this possible in signalR engine itself?

Many thanks to whoever answer.

Comment: SignalR has broken compatibility more than once and the new ASP.NET Core version is no exception. You should look at the new ASP.NET Core version and avoid using any features that have been deprecated otherwise your app will be harder to migrate in the future. BTW you didn't say what platform you are targeting.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input, however i still don't get - where exactly should i look? BTW could you asnwer questions? Platform - most probably Windows: winforms + asp.net

Comment: Most of your questions can be answered on the github page. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues: 2.2.3 was a very minor release consisting of just a single fix: #4036, Intermittent Error: Cannot access a disposed object

Comment: what is diffrence between signalr/signalr2 and asp.net signalr is it all same and what is official signalr website with library description and documentation

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to answer your questions.

1. Already mentioned, only a single fix.
2. It worked for my application, can't really tell if it works for yours. More infos regarding the 2.2.2 release: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.2.2
3. I'm not quite sure what you mean. But yes there were different versions of SignalR other the last years:

   - **SignalR 1** (2012-2014)
   - **SignalR 2** (2014-now | Current version: `2.2.3` | Github: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR)
   - **SignalR '3'** (aka ASP.NET Core SignalR | Release: [mid 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33604800/333404) | Current pre version: `1.0.0-rc1-final` | Github: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR)
4. I guess, not that I'm aware of. See https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/net_library_eula_ENU.htm (SignalR 2) 
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/2.0.0/LICENSE.txt (SignalR 3)
5. Checkout the samples here: https://www.asp.net/signalr They all target SignalR 2 currently and will be updated as soon as ASP.NET Core 2.1 and SignalR '3' is released.
6. Don't know, I haven't changed anything in my code.
7. As already mentioned in 5., they will update the page as soon as ASP.NET Core 2.1 is released (see comment section in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/05/07/asp-net-core-2-1-0-rc1-now-available/ )
8. I guess?
9. Do you mean this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr ?

   10. I'm not aware of a SignalR feature which stores messages. I think you have to implement this yourself.