# ASP.NET 5 (vNext) and SignalR

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core

Is it possible already to use ASP.NET 5 aka ASP.NET Core 1.0 with SignalR?

I saw that it's not yet implemented, but there's a SignalR.Server (version 3) [repo](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server) on github. It contains a couple of samples, but I cannot yet find a full sample with a controller with a hub... :(

I've managed to find examples of how to add SignalR to the project.json file with the line `"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"`, I have added `services.AddSignalR()` and `app.UseSignalR()` to my Startup.cs file, I have also injectd the `IConnectionManager` into the controller, but I have no idea how the controller then goes about sending data to clients...

Answer (score 1):

Here is several samples for SignalR 3.0:

[Any samples for mvc6 with signalr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475804/any-samples-for-mvc6-with-signalr)

[The ASP.NET 5 (vNext) application sample, Real-Time Data Editing](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-ASPNET-vNext-Real-Time-b1d27fe4)

[ASP.NET 5 and SignalR 3](http://www.konda.eu/asp-net-5-and-signalr-3/)

Update (09/17/2016): Here is sample for ASP.NET Core RTM 1.0 :

[GETTING STARTED WITH SIGNALR CORE](https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/signalr-core/)

Comment: I've seen all those samples and did not find anything usable... :(